# Make GNU indent break long comments

Tags: text-processing, c, indentation

Is there a way to convince GNU indent to break long comment and change it to multiline comment?
Something like this:

```
// Very long comment, longer than 80 characters. Just imagine that.
```

To this:

```
/*
 * Very long comment, longer than 80 characters. Just
 * imagine that.
 */
```

I know that formatting second one can be done simply by '-cdb -sc', but I don't know how to ensure line break and comment type change.
Is it even possible?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? because I'm facing the same problem and need to know how to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It seems to not be possible with gnu indent. I didn't find it in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work, for some reason it requires both `-fc1` and `-fca` options:

```
indent -fc1 -fca j.c
```

Alternatively, you can use the Berkeley style:

```
indent -orig j.c
```

Input:

```
// Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, apeirian constituam interpretaris no his, soluta salutandi persequeris vel ne, facete impedit contentiones te eam. Ut utamur habemus qualisque usu
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){puts("hello world");}
```

Output:

```
// Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, apeirian constituam interpretaris no his,
// soluta salutandi persequeris vel ne, facete impedit contentiones te eam.
// Ut utamur habemus qualisque usu
#include <stdio.h>
int
main ()
{
  puts ("hello world");
}
```

[Example](//github.com/svnpenn/rosso/blob/589610a/.indent.pro#L14-L18)

Comment: Partly this is some sort of solution, but it breaks style (multi line comment should be /* */). Idea was that it wouldn't only break to new line but also changed comment type. I will accept this answer after while if no one founds better solution, but it is not exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i '\_//_{s_//_/* _g;s_$_ */_g}' file.c
indent -fc1 -fca -sc -cdb file.c
sed -i 's/\/\*\(.*\)\*\/$/\/\/\1/' file.c
```

does what you requested, but I would be cautious as it probably misses some edge cases

Input:

```
// Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, apeirian constituam interpretaris no his, soluta salutandi persequeris vel ne, facete impedit contentiones te eam. Ut utamur habemus qualisque usu
#include <stdio.h>
int main () // damn
{
  puts ("hello world" /* sheeet */); }              /* oh shit */
```

Output:

```
/*
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, apeirian constituam interpretaris no his,
 * soluta salutandi persequeris vel ne, facete impedit contentiones te eam.
 * Ut utamur habemus qualisque usu
 */
#include <stdio.h>
int
main ()             // damn
{
  puts ("hello world" /* sheeet */ );
}               // oh shit
```